GCC embed binary into a qtabwidget
If there is a similar post out there I have not found it. pleases reply with a link if there is one.
project description:
We have created a modular approach with our projects. for example projectFramework which contains the qtabwidget. then projectA, projectB, -- projectL are treated as a module which get populated into each tab if the specified project is needed for the particular Job.
currently the sub projects(A-L) are built into DLL'S, which are working. However, we need to have each project(A-L) in its own subfolder which becomes a module that can be there or not. Also we do not want the Framework binary to need those folders of libraries if they are not needed for the job. since we are using dll's that means we need to link them into the Framework and since they are linked then they need to exist in there perspective sub-folders.
What We want to do:
We are looking at converting these from dll to exe and then embed the binary GUI into qtabwidget. as an exe we have more control of this modular approach and can prevent the loading of a project if some of our project startup checks fail. Thus preventing any unwanted crash.
Question:
How can we embed a GUI binary into a QTabWidget of another binary project?
Cannot run as a qprocess, since that will run it outside of the Framework and not inside the QTabWidget.
Environment
Windows 10, Msys2, Mingw64, Qt5.15 Qt Creator 4.14
Thank you in advance and would greatly appreciate some ideas to accomplish this.

"since we are using dll's that means we need to link them into the Framework" Not true. See QPluginLoader

Embedding foreign binaries seems way more complicated to me than simply loading DLLs dynamically on demand. (See the LoadLibrary API function on Windows.) But if you do want to do it in the vastly more complicated manner, you can take a look at this question.

thank you Botje, i will look into QPluginLoader.
